# Easiest Way To Parallelize Derivatives

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization

## What I would like to do

I have a Lagrangian (a scalar). Of this function I take the derivative w.r.t. to metric-components. Of the result, I take again a derivative. The formula looks like

$\partial_a\frac{f(t,x,y,z)}{g_{ab}}$,

so, the result is a vector.

## What I do

So far, I just run

```
res0 = D[D[f, g00][t, x, y, z]] , t] + D[D[f, g01[t, x, y, z]] , x] + D[D[f, g02[t, x, y, z]] , y] +  D[D[f, g03[t, x, y, z]] , z]
res1 = D[D[f, g01][t, x, y, z]] , t] + D[D[f, g11[t, x, y, z]] , x] + D[D[f, g12[t, x, y, z]] , y] +  D[D[f, g13[t, x, y, z]] , z]
res2 = D[D[f, g02][t, x, y, z]] , t] + D[D[f, g12[t, x, y, z]] , x] + D[D[f, g22[t, x, y, z]] , y] +  D[D[f, g23[t, x, y, z]] , z]
res3 = D[D[f, g03][t, x, y, z]] , t] + D[D[f, g13[t, x, y, z]] , x] + D[D[f, g23[t, x, y, z]] , y] +  D[D[f, g33[t, x, y, z]] , z]
```

which gives me the vector components.

## What I'd like to know

Can I speed this up? `res0/1/2/3` do not depend on each other, so I think those could be run in parallel. But also, the various derivatives of `f` are not depending on each other, so those could also be run in parallel. What is the easiest way to parallelize this? (Or is there something else I could do to make it run through faster?) I thought maybe writing it as a matrix and using one of the built-in `parallel-`functions, but I do not really need to get a matrix or a vector back, but it would do no harm and look nice.

Thank you very much in advance. :) Happy Holidays!